# Mudblazor Select "broken" on Popover

Tags: html, css, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have a MudSelect on a MudPopover but I encounter a somewhat weird behavior when using the select. The select dropdown will not appear over everything else as it should, but instead, it will be layered behind /underneath other components and is unclickable. The confusing thing about this is that a simple reload (when opening the page) fixes the issue. Does somebody know what triggers the "broken" behavior and how it is then fixed by reloading? Or does somebody know how to fix it without forcing a reload upon entering the page?

[when it is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7YKN.png)

[how it should normally look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09ZFw.png)

```
<MudPopover Open="@_open" RelativeWidth="true" Fixed="true">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <EditForm Model="@items" Context="itemUpload">
            <MudSelect @bind-Value="selectedH" Margin="Margin.Dense" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Label="whatever" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter">
                @foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    <MudSelectItem Value="@item.id">@item.name</MudSelectItem>
                }
            </MudSelect>
        </EditForm>
        <MudButton Disabled="@uploading" OnClick="Upload" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary">
            @if (uploading)
            {
                <MudProgressCircular Class="ms-n1" Size="Size.Small" Indeterminate="true"/>
                <MudText Class="ms-2">Processing</MudText>
            }
            else
            {
                <MudText>Upload</MudText>
            }
        </MudButton>
        <MudButton OnClick="@ToggleOpen" Class="ml-auto mr-n3 mb-1" Color="Color.Error">Schlie&szlig;en</MudButton>
    </div>
</MudPopover>
```

Comment: 0

I'm seeing this same behaviour and it does seem to be something to do with the contexts of z-index within nested MudPopOvers (MudSelect uses MudPopOver).

Did you manage to get this working in the end?

Comment: No sorry I never tried to fix it afterwards. I changed the UI and went with MudDialog instead. This componenent is working correctly and you can sort of replace the MudPopOver with it. Not the cleanest solution though.

Comment: I am also seeing this behavior, for what it's worth. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

@InCo placed this in the comments, but it appears to be the best solution I have seen, so I pulled this out into an answer.   Instead of using `MudPopover`, use `MudDialog`.  It solves the Z-Index issue for `MudSelect` as well as `MudDatePicker`